# How to Adjust div in mobile view jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

How can i adjust my layout in mobile.

For Example : My layout show the information in alternative pattern,One side picture and other is text. Like this

Picture - Text

Text    - Picture

Picture - Text

Text    - Picture

**But currently it shows layout in mobile as like this**

Text

Picture

Picture

Text

Text.....

**I want to show in mobile as :**

Picture

Text

Picture

Text....

**For resolve this issue: i code it with jquery, Here is my code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera //Mini  /i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 jQuery(".picture-div").css({"float": "left"}); 
 jQuery(".text-div").css({"float": "right"});
 }
});
```

Comment: I think you can do this by `media-query` also

Comment: How can i achieve it in media query..?

Comment: you can mention the width of screen and according to that you can style each and every tags in your way for any screens

Comment: Okay, Tried but d'ont know what should be code next

Comment: show some sample html if possible...

Comment: can you show some code we can help

Comment: [link] http://smartcastle.in/smart-lighting/

Comment: A. don't use JavaScript for styling! If you want to detect mobile use `modernizr` (https://modernizr.com/) than use the mobile class `html.touch` or something like that. B. If you want to show those element in separate rows, do it from the server.

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler to do this with CSS media queries rather than relying on Javascript.

Reconfigure your HTML as follows

> Picture - Text
>
> Picture - Text
>
> Picture - Text
>
> Picture - Text

Then float alternate rows to appear on opposite sides on each row. Then on mobile you just need to make the widths 100% and they will appear in the order desired

An example:

**HTML**

```
 <div class="row row-even">
      <div class="picture">Picture</div>
      <div class="text">Text</div>
 </div>

 <div class="row row-odd">
      <div class="picture">Picture</div>
      <div class="text">Text</div>
 </div>

 <div class="row row-even">
      <div class="picture">Picture</div>
      <div class="text">Text</div>
 </div>

 <div class="row row-odd">
      <div class="picture">Picture</div>
      <div class="text">Text</div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .row {
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
 }
 .row div {
      width: 50%;
 }
 .row-even .picture, .row-odd text {
      float: left;
 }
 .row-odd .picture, .row-even text {
      float: right;
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
      .row div {
           width: 100%;     
      }    
 }
```